# JsonWebTokenError: Can't verify jwt

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I  make the token here:

`var token = jwt.sign(user, new_secret, {expiresIn: 10000});`

Then I attempt to verify it here

```
var token = req.headers.authorization;

jwt.verify(token, new_secret, function(err, decoded) { 
    console.log(err);    
  if (err) {
    return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });    
  } else {
    // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
    req.decoded = decoded;    
    next();
  }
});
```

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong here. I'm new to jwt.

Comment: what's the package you use here? I'm referring to `jwt`.

Comment: `JsonWebTokenError: Can't verify jwt` is that the complete error ?

Comment: node-jsonwebtoken is the package

Comment: { [JsonWebTokenError: invalid token] name: 'JsonWebTokenError', message: 'invalid token' } is the error

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by changing the prefix on the client side using angular-jwt.

It was once 'Bearer'; I found evidence that it should be 'JWT'...it only worked by removing it entirely:

`jwtInterceptorProvider.authPrefix = '';`

I'm not sure if this is best practice or not.